# "1292 Incorrect datetime value" when updating an "empty" datetime field

Tags: mysql, update, datetime

I have an `updated_at` field that was not initially set with default datetime value on the server. For a short period, a bunch of records got inserted with an "empty" value and are showing up at `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in the `updated_at` column. I wrote am update command to copy the values of the `created_at` field to `updated_at` and it is updating the field correctly, however, when I run it in MySQL Workbench, I get the following warning:

```
6 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '' Rows matched: 6  Changed: 6  Warnings: 1
```

My query:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET updated_at=created_at
WHERE updated_at='' and id >0;
```

I'm not sure where that warning is coming from since the `created_at` times are all valid and the `updated_at` fields are being set with the correct data.

Comment: given that your output said it changed 6 rows maybe nothing is required.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulation on your commitment to clean dates.

Temporary disabling the `NO_ZERO_DATE` `sql_mode` will enable this cleanup.

Just to be sure, use `0000-00-00 00:00:00` as the date too.

```
SET @@SQL_MODE = REPLACE(@@SQL_MODE, 'NO_ZERO_DATE', '');
UPDATE mytable
SET updated_at=created_at
WHERE (updated_at='' OR updated_at='0000-00-00 00:00:00') and id >0;
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be some `NULL` and `0000-00-00 00:00:00` values in `created_at` that's why it's showing `1 warning`. You can cross check it with the below query :

```
select created_at , updated_at
from mytable
where ( (updated_at='' OR updated_at='0000-00-00 00:00:00') OR
(created_at='' OR created_at='0000-00-00 00:00:00') )
and id > 0 ;
```

You can update this values with some specific time or current timestamp.

To ignore this kind of values you strict the instance using below parameter as @danblack suggested :

`set global sql_mode=<< you current value>> + ,NO_ZERO_DATE`